# Snowflake BIT datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have BIT data type in sql server and i am trying to migrate it to snowflake
but i am not able get the data into snowflake properly 
0 goes as 0 but 1 goes into as 255 when i DT_UI1 data type to output the column in sql server

can anybody help me how to send bit data type column to snowflake

Comment: I'm curious (other than the answer below suggesting a signed integer `DT_I1`) if using `DT_BOOL` for your single bit value would be more appropriate. I'm not sure how that would get translated on the snowflake side since there isn't a bool type (or even a single bit type). I would hope that a bool would be passed as a 1 or 0 to a `NUMBER` type though.

Comment: In all likelihood you get 255 because the `BIT` is considered a boolean `true`, which is in turn represented as -1 internally, which, in turn, is 255 when converted to an unsigned value (note that this has nothing to do with SQL Server, which doesn't consider `BIT` a boolean type and has no values internally to represent `TRUE` or `FALSE` at all). JNevill should be right on the money: read it as a `DT_BOOL` if possible or insert a conversion to that if not.

Comment: i actually found a website which helped me to convert the bit data type

Comment: https://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/ssis-truefalse-and-10-values-on-bit-columns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DT_UI1 is probably an **unsigned** integer and you want a regular signed integer.

Failing that you can just select instead

```
CASE WHEN [BitColumn] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

or

```
CAST([BitColumn] AS INT)
```

To get an integer on the source side